# how to dynamically create value type and assign value in .net

Tags: reflection, .net-3.5

I have:

- data type (all types are values types) as `string` (for example: **'System.Boolean'**)
- data value as `string` (for example: **'true'**)

I have to get:

- instance of value type
- this instance should be initialized by that value

I have started from

```
object v = Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type.GetType('type as string', true, true),..);
```

and I don't know how to initialize `v` to value: how can I convert *dynamically* value as string to bool (or other value types) and assign it to v?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx)?

```
object v = Convert.ChangeType(text, Type.GetType(typeName));
```

That will only work for certain target types, but that may be enough for you.

EDIT: Ultimately, you'll need a set of types you want to support. You may want to have some sort of `Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>>` and a method which is able to disguise how you handle more general cases (such as enums).

Comment: @garik: I don't know - have you tried it? (It should take long to test.) Ultimately, do you have a list of the types you need to support?